# Read POSTed JSON data from the request body

Tags: request, https

Is there a way with the request service to read POSTed JSON from `php://input`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [getRestParams()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getRestParams-detail) like so: `$input = craft()->request->getRestParams()`

A bit confusing naming there, which is why it's changing to `getBodyParams()` in Yii 2.